# How to make the admin side display and player side display interactive in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I am developing a Quiz App using flutter framework and firestore as it's database. It allows admin to create rooms and publish quiz in the room. The players need to join the room and wait until the admin clicks on the
"Start Quiz" button situated in the Appbar of admin side display of room. The clicking "Start Quiz", the admin side navigates to a results page(where he could see realtime results) and the player side navigates to questions display where he starts answering question. I am not getting how to implement this.

Admin side room display

[image]

Player side room display

[image]

These are the code of the two pages

Display_playerSide.dart

```
> class PlayerSideDisplay extends StatefulWidget {
  // const PlayerSideDisplay({super.key});
  final String RoomID;
  PlayerSideDisplay({required this.RoomID});


  @override
  State<PlayerSideDisplay> createState() => _PlayerSideDisplayState();
}

class _PlayerSideDisplayState extends State<PlayerSideDisplay> {
  DatabaseService _databaseInstance = new DatabaseService();

  Stream playerstream = Stream.empty();
  Widget playerList() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
      child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: playerstream,
          builder: ((context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            return snapshot.data == null
                ? Container()
                : ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                    itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                      return PlayerTile(
                          playerID: snapshot.data!.docs
                              .elementAt(index)
                              .get("player"));
                    }));
          })),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    _databaseInstance.GetPlayers(widget.RoomID).then((value) {
      setState(() {
        playerstream = value;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[800],
        title: Text("Players"),
      ),
      body: playerList(),
    );
    ;
  }
}

class PlayerTile extends StatelessWidget {
  // const PlayerTile({super.key});

  final String playerID;
  PlayerTile({required this.playerID});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration:
          BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 3)),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, top: 7),
      height: 100,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            child: Image.network(
              "https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/166/166344.png",
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 48,
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  "Player ID :$playerID",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 18,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

player_displayAdmin.dart

```
> class DisplayPlayers extends StatefulWidget {
  // const DisplayPlayers({super.key});
  final String RoomID;
  DisplayPlayers(this.RoomID);


  @override
  State<DisplayPlayers> createState() => _DisplayPlayersState();
}

class _DisplayPlayersState extends State<DisplayPlayers> {
  DatabaseService _databaseInstance = new DatabaseService();

  Stream playerstream = Stream.empty();
  Widget playerList() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
      child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: playerstream,
          builder: ((context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            return snapshot.data == null
                ? Container()
                : ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                    itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                      return PlayerTile(
                          playerID: snapshot.data!.docs
                              .elementAt(index)
                              .get("player"));
                    }));
          })),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    _databaseInstance.GetPlayers(widget.RoomID).then((value) {
      setState(() {
        playerstream = value;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[800],
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton.icon(
              onPressed: (() {}),
              icon: Icon(Icons.quiz_sharp),
              label: Text("Start Quiz"))
        ],
        title: Text("Players"),
      ),
      body: playerList(),
    );
  }
}

class PlayerTile extends StatelessWidget {
  // const PlayerTile({super.key});

  final String playerID;
  PlayerTile({required this.playerID});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration:
          BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 3)),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, top: 7),
      height: 100,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            child: Image.network(
              "https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/166/166344.png",
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 48,
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  "Player ID :$playerID",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 18,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```